# Unable to host an NServiceBus Saga from another Service with SQL Persistence

Tags: msbuild, nservicebus, nservicebus-sagas

I am attempting to host a Saga from one project in another project using NServiceBus 6 with `SqlPersistence` and `SqlDialect.MsSqlServer`. In most examples I have found, the Saga is contained in the same assembly as the hosting app, and perhaps this is why I am struggling.

When hosting everything in the same app, the `NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql.MsBuild` package correctly outputs Saga `.sql` files during the build and then picks these up and executes them on run. Using a separate app, only the `Outbox`, `Subscription` and `Timeout` `.sql` files are generated, not the Saga ones. The following entry is then logged on run:

> INFO  NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql.Installer Directory '[PATH]\SagaPersistence\Service\bin\Debug\NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql\MsSqlServer\Sagas' not found so no saga creation scripts will be executed.

A full VS 2017 repro may be found at https://github.com/WolfyUK/NServiceBusSagaSqlPersistence.

Firstly, is it a bad idea to host a Sagas from another service, rather than being self-hosted? If not, can someone advise the best way to resolve the SQL Persistence issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add `NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql.MsBuild` to the `Saga` project? The scripts should then be found there. Unfortunately they're not copied to the host its folder, so you'll have to take them from there into production. Or have them generated by using `EnableInstallers`, like you're already doing.

Comment: I have since realised that the Saga scripts _are_ outputted to the `bin` folder on the second project but only on `Rebuild`. On `Build` or `Debug` the files are cleared out.

Comment: You can add the `NServiceBus.Persistence.Sql` package directly to the host project.  That will get the SQL scripts created under the `bin` folder of the host project.